Adding items to recycler view with shared data between activity and fragment with view model
I am new to Kotlin, I am trying to work on an app that works with an embedded system trough Firebase. After I made the communication with a shared view model between the activity and fragment, I tried adding the alarm data to the recycler view. I used the observe function for live data, but every time I try to add new alarms to the alarm list it seems like the alarm created earlier is replaced by the new one. I expected a new instance for it, but I figured that the elements added to the recycler view are tied in a way to the live data
I tried introducing a flag and passing the data to a new var but I did not succeed
Alarm list is an object created to hold the array of alarms
and Alarm is the object passed trough the adapter
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val itemAdapter = Adapter(alarmlist)
        // Set the LayoutManager that
        // this RecyclerView will use.
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = binding.recycleView
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        // adapter instance is set to the
        // recyclerview to inflate the items.
        recyclerView.adapter = itemAdapter
        var flag = false
        var v= Alarm("","",0,"")
        sharedViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

            println(it)
            v = it
            alarmlist.add(it)
        }

    }

the array that is the alarmlist is a object named constants
package com.example.ex

object Constants {
    fun getAlarmData():ArrayList<Alarm>{
        // create an arraylist of type employee class
        val alarmList=ArrayList<Alarm>()
        val emp1=Alarm("12 mai 1999","21:10", 1021,"")
        alarmList.add(emp1)
        val emp2=Alarm("12 mai 1999","21:10", 1021,"")
        alarmList.add(emp2)
        return  alarmList
    }
}

When i try to notify the adapter with notifydatasetchanged there is no need and the alarm is still added. I think that is because i hold the array in the object constants
By saying the alarm get replaced and is dependent on the lifecycle of the live data I mean that each time I go trough my alarmActivity(where you set the parameters of the new alarm)the alarm that was set is replaced with the live data. The first lines of code in the message are what inputs the new alarm, but it just replaces the data in the one created earlier, basically I cant create new alarms, just replace one in the view holder with newly inputted data in the alarm activity
enter image description here
This is the adapter(very simple adapter)
package com.example.ex
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class Adapter(private val alarmlist1: ArrayList<Alarm>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    // This method creates a new ViewHolder object for each item in the RecyclerView
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        // Inflate the layout for each item and return a new ViewHolder object
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_alarm, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    // This method returns the total
    // number of items in the data set
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return alarmlist1.size
    }

    // This method binds the data to the ViewHolder object
    // for each item in the RecyclerView
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentEmp = alarmlist1[position]
        holder.name.text = currentEmp.data
        holder.email.text = currentEmp.timp
        holder.timp.text = currentEmp.releuri.toString()
    }

    // This class defines the ViewHolder object for each item in the RecyclerView
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timp)
        val email: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.data)
        val timp:TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.releuri)
    }
}

and this is alarm list object
package com.example.ex

object Constants {
    fun getAlarmData():ArrayList<Alarm>{
      
        val alarmList=ArrayList<Alarm>()
        val emp1=Alarm("12 mai 1999","21:10", 1021,"")
        alarmList.add(emp1)
        val emp2=Alarm("12 mai 1999","21:10", 1021,"")
        alarmList.add(emp2)
        return  alarmList
    }
}


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Please explain "it seems like the alarm created earlier is replaced by the new one".
Also, you are adding to "alarmList", which I assume is a List in the current class, but not updating the adapter, so you would not see changes reflected in the UI.

@dominicoder I tried to do my best explaining

You should probably show how alarmList is created and used and what your adapter looks like.

@dominicoder I added alarmlist, the object that holds the array (cosnstans) and the adapter

You have not shown what alarmlist is. Where does the alaramlist in val itemAdapter = Adapter(alarmlist) in onCreateView come from? Where is getAlarmData() used?
